# How to give JFrame initial focus

Tags: java, swing, jframe

What's the method that allows you to use the `JFrame` without clicking on it first? I have a game, but in order to move with WASD I first need to click on the frame when the application is run. Isn't there a method that makes it so you can use it straight away without clicking first?

I have this:

```
Game game = new Game();
game.frame.setResizable(false);
game.frame.setTitle(Game.title);
game.frame.add(game);
game.frame.pack();
game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
game.frame.setVisible(true);
```

Where should I put `game.frame.requestFocus();`?

Comment: try Sysout(game.frame.requestFocusInWindow()) , also you should requestFocusInWindow for a container like a JPanel , not for a JFrame

Answer (score 2):

It is the requestFocus() method, which puts the focus on the component that called it (JFrame in this case).

Comment: Before you call game.frame.setVisible(true) call game.frame.requestFocus()

Comment: Didn't work :/

It's in the main method if that helps? Also, the way I've done it is added key listeners, and if W is pressed, print: true, false, false, false. If A is pressed, print: false, true, false, false etc. Therefore, if nothing is pressed, print: false, false, false, false. It's displaying full false when I press those buttons, until I click on the JFrame :/

Comment: Try putting requestFocus on the very last line. I believe that the component has to be visible before you can request focus.

Comment: That makes sense, but it didn't work :/

Maybe it's just my laptop? :P

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your asking how to set the focus.

Have a look at: [How to focus a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641172/how-to-focus-a-jframe)

Answer (score 0):

It is the requestFocus() method. This puts the focus on the component that called it. You may want to have a look at the following documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html