# Loosing focus on the frame on click of ok button on joption pane

Tags: jframe

I have created a panel which displays scaled images .On clicked on the scaled image, I shows the image with larger view in a frame.When I cropped the area on frame it shows cropped image in Joption pane and when I clicked ok , It returns the focus on to the main Panel and frame with enlarge view of image get minimized.

Here i dont want to loose the focus on the enlarge image frame view. Is any one can help me out with it.

```
enter code here
        imgPane = new CropImagePane(imagePath);
        frame= new MyFrame("Crop Area");
        frame.add(imgPane);
        frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.toFront();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hi Got the answer.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641172/how-to-focus-a-jframe.  Thanks