# Is it good way to open new Jframe and close previous?

Tags: java

I have 3 Jframe, when I click on first Jframe, it closes it and opens new, is there any way to call second jframe on this window?

Comment: Are you trying to set focus on a JFrame, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641172/how-to-focus-a-jframe ?

Comment: Karol Dowbecki setVisible true or false is also an option